# for axum, how to set a header for a handler

Tags: rust, http-headers, response-headers, rust-axum

I can't seem to find how to set a header for the response.

I have looked for how to do this but haven't found a **straightforward** way to do this.

With specific emphasis on the `content-type` header, How to set both a standard & custom headers from a response handler bearing in mind that I can already do `thing.into_response()`.

Comment: Are [the docs](https://docs.rs/axum/latest/axum/response/index.html) not clear enough?

Comment: They are if you're handler returns `impl IntoResponse`, my handler returns a `Response` directly otherwise the doc's would have been fine. I did mention `bearing in mind that I can already do thing.into_response()`

Comment: Then why want you return `impl IntoResponse`? Or just call `into_response()`, what is bad with that?

Comment: I can't return `impl IntoResponse` (so I don't) and I do call `into_response()`, I'm not sure what you're trying to say.

Comment: Why can't you return `impl IntoResponse`? And I meant that I don't understand why you seek alternatives if you already know that you can call `into_response()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is an example how you can set a custom response header in your handler:

```
use axum::http::HeaderMap;
use axum::response::IntoResponse;

async fn my_handler() -> impl IntoResponse {
    let mut headers = HeaderMap::new();
    headers.insert("x-my-hdr", "abc".parse().unwrap());
    (headers, "It works!")
}
```

I've tested the above with both custom and standard headers (such as `Content-Type`) and it seems to work in both cases.

Comment: @NoahMcIlraith nice one :) I added the imports to the example.